# How to increase the number from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a maintenance system for various applications, and I'm stuck at an arithmetic problem.

For the string which is 2.1.0 now, I want to add 0.0.1 to 2.1.0, so it will be 2.1.1. What algorithm can I use?

Comment: You set the version number for a VB.NET Windows application in the project properties.

Comment: [I edited your question a bit - if I changed the meaning please edit it to return it to what you intended.]

Comment: It is not a number, it is a string.  Numbers never have more than one decimal point.  Flip that mental switch and you'll surely find the String.Split() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the individual parts (separated by dots), convert them from strings to integers, add the increment to the version, then join the parts back together into a string.

There are many ways to code that, for example:

```
Dim s = "2.1.0"
Dim t = "0.0.1"

Dim n = String.Join(".", s.Split("."c).Zip(t.Split("."c), Function(a, b) CInt(a) + CInt(b)))

Console.WriteLine(n)
```

outputs the string

> 2.1.1

---

Alternatively, if you want to use the [Version class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.7.2), it is a bit more fiddly:

```
Dim s = "2.1.0"
Dim t = "0.0.1"

Dim v = Version.Parse(s)
Dim inc = Version.Parse(t)

Dim maj = v.Major + inc.Major
Dim min = v.Minor + inc.Minor
Dim build = If(v.Build >= 0 OrElse inc.Build >= 0, Math.Max(v.Build, 0) + Math.Max(inc.Build, 0), -1)
Dim rev = If(v.Revision >= 0 OrElse inc.Revision >= 0, Math.Max(v.Revision, 0) + Math.Max(inc.Revision, 0), -1)

Dim n As Version
If rev >= 0 Then
    n = New Version(maj, min, build, rev)
ElseIf build >= 0 Then
    n = New Version(maj, min, build)
Else
    n = New Version(maj, min)
End If

Console.WriteLine(n)
```